# How to troubleshoot a routing issue

Tags: windows, networking, routing, windows-10

I am running into a weird problem suddenly. I have Windows 10 on my computer and I have a Hyper-V virtual machine on my computer that runs Windows Server 2019. Inside this, I am hosting a web site. All of the sudden, today, I cannot access my website from my Windows 10 host computer. Externally, it works fine.

My external IP address if 1.2.3.4 (this is fictitious). If I have my girlfriend open Chrome on her computer at home and she puts in https://1.2.3.4, the site comes up just fine. If I go to my Windows 10 host computer and open chrome and put in https://1.2.3.4, it doesn't work. It's like somehow my external address is getting routed differently on my local computer then it is with every other computer.

Is there some way I can diagnose this and maybe refresh my routing tables and/or trace the route to see exactly where my http request is going?

And just to let everyone know, this is a new issue. It worked perfect yesterday.

Comment: "_My external IP address if 1.2.3.4 (this is fictitious)._" IANA has set aside three address ranges for such things: `192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`. Please do not use addresses that belong to someone else. Use addressing from one of the three ranges set aside for that. Your question has live links to an address that you do not own.

Comment: Do you have any security or AV software installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing anything to work with so I need to make assumption that
VM and Host are on the same broadcast domain and in the same IP subnet.

- From the host ping IP of the VM
- In the Host, check arp table for VM's MAC
- In the VM, check arp table for host's MAC
- If ARP tables show MACs correctly, L2 works
- If you are missing MACs in ARP you should capture packets to see which operating system has issue with ARP
- you may want to allow ICMP in both OSs just to make sure the pings
  will work as well, so you can confirm L3
- if L3 is working, then move layer up and see if the connection between two OSes is being established with `netstat -on`
- if the connection is OK, then you need to look what is happening in the web server... (this point can grow too wide without knowing details of your server)